# Code works much slower on production server

Tags: c#, performance, iis

I have some legacy code which is pretty basic. Code extracts files from ZIP file, de-serializes contents of the file from the ZIP from XML to objects, and does something with that objects.

Zip file is around 90mb. Problem with this is that this code executes around 3 seconds on local machine (1.5 sec to extract, and around 1.3 sec to deserialize all files), but when i publish that code on Windows server and IIS 6.1, it takes around 28 seconds to do the same action with same file. 14 sec to extract and 13 secs to deserialize.

Server is VPS, 8 cores, 16GB RAM.

Does anyone have any ideas?

```
 public List<FileNameStream> UnzipFilesTest(List<string> files, string zippedPathAndFile)
        {
            //var result = new Dictionary<string, MemoryStream>();
            var unzipedFiles = new List<FileNameStream>();
            string file1 = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(zippedPathAndFile);


            if (File.Exists(file1))
            {

                using (MemoryStream data = new MemoryStream())
                {

                    using (Ionic.Zip.ZipFile zipFile = Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.Read(file1))
                    {
                        zipFile.ParallelDeflateThreshold = -1;
                        foreach (ZipEntry e in zipFile)
                        {

                            if (files.Contains(e.FileName, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                            {

                                e.Extract(data);

                                unzipedFiles.Add(new FileNameStream() { FileContent = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fs..ToArray()), FileName = e.FileName }); //(e.FileName, data);

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


            return unzipedFiles;
        }
```

Comment: Probably hard drive problem, SSD vs HDD ?

Comment: 90mb file and that much of a difference? Btw local machine does not have SSD

Comment: Is the zip file on the server or being accessed over a network?

Comment: No. Locally by IIS worker process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was something in the VPS itself. After 7 days of research, hosting provider staff offered to migrate to a new machine, and everything seems to be in order now.

Answer (score 2):

Optimizing the foreach loop using a Parallel.Foreach loop will schedule the work of unzipping the files using multiple threads. The more threads the faster it will go. I am not saying it isn't a hardware, network, firewall or antivirus issue on the server - but it isn't wise to throw hardware at a software problem.

Here is a [MSDN Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720(v=vs.110).aspx) that may prove useful.

Your code would look something like:

```
Parallel.ForEach(zipEntires, (e) =>
{
   if (files.Contains(e.FileName, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
   {
      e.Extract(data);
      unzipedFiles.Add(new FileNameStream() { FileContent = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fs..ToArray()), FileName = e.FileName }); //(e.FileName, data);
   }
}
```